# Symbol aligned with an equation does not work

Tags: symbols, newtheorem

I want my theorems be ended by a diamond. It works fine, except when there is an equation at the end, then the diamond is in a new, empty line. With the following MWE, I get this:
[image: this here]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=15, BCOR = 10mm,parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand{\thmend}{\hfill\mbox{$\diamond$}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This works fince because it's in one line. \thmend
    \end{thm}
    
    \begin{thm}
        This does not work because:
        \[
        1+2=3 
        \]\thmend
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

If I set `\thmend` right after the equation, the diamond comes right after the 3 and not at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) to create a new style for theorems including a "QED symbol". This allows to use `\qedhere` in theorems to place the symbol in equations, for example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[qed=$\diamond$]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=thm, name=Theorem]{thm}
\begin{document}
    \begin{thm}
        This works fince because it's in one line.
    \end{thm}
    
    \begin{thm}
        This does not work because:
        \[
        1+2=3 \qedhere
        \]
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice suggestion.

Comment: This works, thank you! Can you yet tell me how I can link the counter I already used? Something like
\declaretheoremstyle[qed=$\diamond$]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=thm, name=Theorem]{Theorem}[Iamthecounter]

Comment: @mathquester you can use the key `numberlike=counter` in the options of `\declaretheorem`. There are more details in the manual of `thmtools`.